# Casting chars to integers gives unexpected values

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var stringNumber = 93.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var stringArray = stringNumber.ToCharArray();
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

What I would expect `intArray` to contain are the values `9` and `3` but instead it contains `57` and `51` and I'm not sure why? How would I get `intArray` to contain the expected values?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You're casting a `char` to its numeric representation. That brings you to its ASCII code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, by default, casting a character to an integer returns the ASCII value of that character.

You could use `int.Parse()` instead:

```
var stringNumber = 93.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var stringArray = stringNumber.ToCharArray();
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Char.GetNumericValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
int[] intArray = 93.ToString()
                 .ToCharArray()
                 .Select(r=> (int) char.GetNumericValue(r))
                 .ToArray();
```

If your number is `int` you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580343/961113) for getting an `int` array without converting it to string.

Comment: +1. I've been working with .NET for many years and I never encountered or used the `char.GetNumericValue` method. It's always nice to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a `char` to its `numeric representation`. Try this using `int.Parse()`:

```
var stringNumber = 93.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var stringArray = stringNumber.ToCharArray();
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You get 57 instead of 9 because casting a char to int will get char's decimal value

9 is 57 according to this encoding http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0039/index.htm

3 is 51 according to this encoding(same) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0033/index.htm

To get the actual value of the char you must  parse that value to int `int.Parse(x)`:

```
        var stringNumber = 93.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var stringArray = stringNumber.ToCharArray();
        var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you convert `'9'` char to `int` *code rapresentation*.

```
stringArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because that is the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com) for 3 and 9.

It is converting correctly, You are just getting the char code. Try

```
int.Parse(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const int offset = (int) '0';
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => ((int) x) - offset).ToArray();
```

The problem with your code is that `char` values are internally represented as integers. However, the integer value is the **code** of the character, not the value of that character converted to integer. For instance the code of the character `0` is the integer `48`, according to the [ASCII character table](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table).

The above code takes the value of the character `'0'` and subtracts it from the character value of your array. This works, because in ASCII digits are stored sequentially - the digits from `0` to `9` are spread from code `48` to code `57`. Subtracting the code value of zero, will essentially generate the result you desire. The good thing about this approach, is that it does not depend on the default encoding you are using (although I don't know if there is an encoding which does not respect the ASCII characters' order), and because you do not need to memorize the character code yourself.