# How to convert int to int[] and byte[] to byte[][]?

Tags: c#

How can I convert `int` to `int[]` and `byte[]` to `byte[][]`.

I need to retrieve a list of data from database. I will store in the `int[]` and `byte[][]`.

Comment: Too vague. What kind of data are you handling, and what are you _really_ trying to do with it? What's the relation between the ints and the bytes?

Comment: Have a look at this answer : :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580261/integer-to-integer-array-c-sharp

Comment: If you're retrieving an integer then why not just store it in an integer?..

Comment: seems very odd i dont think you are expressing what you truly want. Try give an example if you can

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert it. If you want to store a `int` into a `int[]` you have to create a new array and put it in the first possition.

Same with `byte[]`

```
int i = 1;
int[] i2 = new int[] { i };

byte[] b2 = new byte[] { 1 };
byte[][] b3 = new byte[][] { b2 };
```

Comment: This would become pretty useless as soon as the op wants to add another integer or byte array to these arrays.

Comment: True, i assume OP has some interfaces which expect those types

Comment: @fubo love your response! agreed ;-)

Comment: Thank guys! for the help! it really work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to store?
`int` and `byte` store just 1 number or one byte.

`int[]` and `byte[]` are 1 dimensional arrays. Hence they store multiple `int`, and `byte` objects.
Example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

`int[][]` and `byte[][]` are 2 dimensional arrays. You can think of them that they store multiple `int[]` and `byte[]` arrays.
Example:

```
int[,] a = new int[,] {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}};
```

Think of it as having 2 rows:

```
{1,3,5,7} 
{2,4,6,8}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: `int[,] != int[][]` - multidimensional `!=` array of arrays (jagged arrays)

Comment: thanks! it really works!